# How to deploy tpm2-tools in a docker container

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, dockerfile, tpm

I'm trying to deploy a TPM service inside a docker container following the instructions detailed in https://github.com/vchatterji/tpm2-luks (this process perfectly worked for me on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04 installed).

Everything works well until **TPM-ABRMD** service is required to be enabled, thus needing to execute `udevadm` and `systemctl` commands in order to restart udev rules and enable+activate the service.

Neither of these commands are available from inside my docker container by default, and although I figured out a workaround for being able to use `udevadm` and manually set the symlinks associated with `systemctl enable`, it wasn't enough to start ABRMD service.

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried many other possibilities and none has worked.

I'm using docker-compose, and the container in which I'd like to install this service has this **docker-compose.yml** file associated:

```
version: '3'
services:

  api:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
    image: api
    container_name: api
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${API_EXTERNAL_PORT}:8080
    depends_on:
      - sql
    environment:
      HOST_DB: sql
      PORT_DB: 3306
      NAME_DB: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      PASSWORD_DB: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      USER_DB: ${MYSQL_USER}
```

And the following **Dockerfile** (inside /dockerfiles):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

ENV JAVA_OPTS ""

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.secutiry.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app/app.war"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Docker environments are fundamentally different from VMs, and if an application requires systemctl and (especially) udev, it will not run well in Docker; containers generally don't run systemd and don't have access to the host hardware devices that udevd requires.